# Sending firebase notifications to specific url

Tags: reactjs, firebase, spring-mvc

I have 2 web portals made in Spring MVC and Reactjs the Spring MVC portal has dynamic URLs as `www.localhost:8080/user1` `www.localhost:8080/user2` and so on, is there a way in firebase to send notifications to `www.localhost:8080/user1`  when some sort of update happens in the ReactJs applications, both are connected to the same API. And I tried the cloud messaging tutorials available in the firebase documentation but none of them worked. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "some sort of update"? Could be anything, really.

Comment: @JanisJansen well from the Reacts applications user can vote, and comment on the users profile so when that happens i need to send a notification to the specific url